# php sprintf not working as expected

Tags: php, wordpress, printf

```
$actions = array(
    'EDIT'   => sprintf('<a href="admin-ajax.php?action=%s&subaction=%s&course_id=%d" class="%s" id="%s">Edit</a>',
                    'abf_cm',
                    'edit_course',
                    $item['course_id'],
                    'thickbox edit-box',
                    'edit_'.$item['course_id']
                    ),
    'DELETE'    => sprintf('<a href="?page=%s&task=%s&action=%s&bookid=%s&noheader=true">Delete</a>','course_management','do_process','delete',$item['course_id']),
);
```

In doing so, the edit part is not being displayed.Am i doing anything wrong.
I also tried using the placeholders

```
'EDIT'   => sprintf('<a href="admin-ajax.php?action=%1$s&subaction=%2$s&course_id=%4$d" class="%4$s" id="%5$s">Edit</a>',
                    'abf_cm',
                    'edit_course',
                    $item['course_id'],
                    'thickbox edit-box',
                    'edit_'.$item['course_id']
                    ),
```

but still no results. **I also noticed that when i remove the class and id attributes in the earlier version, then it works fine.**

Can you please give me a satisfactory explanation of this and tell me where am  i doing wrong.

EDIT:

Im using this inside Wordpress for creating custom table using WP_List_Table class

```
    function column_course_name($item ) {

    //Build row actions
    $actions = array(
        'EDIT'      => sprintf('<a href="admin-ajax.php?action=%s&subaction=%s&course_id=%d" class="%s" id="%s">Edit</a>',
                        'abf_cm',
                        'edit_course',
                        $item['course_id'],
                        'thickbox edit-box',
                        'edit_'.$item['course_id']
                        ),
        'DELETE'    => sprintf('<a href="?page=%s&task=%s&action=%s&bookid=%s&noheader=true">Delete</a>','book_management','do_process','delete',$item['course_id']),
    );

    //Return the title contents
    return sprintf('<a href="?page=book_management&action=viewnedit&bookid=%2$s">%1$s</a>%3$s',
        /*$1%s*/ strlen($item['course_name'])>0?$item['course_name']:'<span style="color:silver">(No Name)</span>',
        /*$2%s*/ $item['course_id'],
        /*$3%s*/ $this->row_actions($actions) //row_actions is a method in this class
    ); 
}
```

*update:*
**Well, its strange to mention but the code works when i use a single class( ie when i delete the space between the two classes for the  tag) .**

Any thoughts?

Comment: "not being displayed"? None of your code displays anything.

Comment: What do you mean by "is not being displayed"? What does that `sprintf` call return?

Comment: You code works perfectly for me.

Comment: try "print_r($actions);" Has it changed the 'EDIT' key in the array?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams,@deceze :of course i print it later (yes, not in the code above).

Comment: @Adam print_r has no value for the index edit

Comment: _...noticed that when i remove the class and id attributes in the earlier version, then it works fine_ ---- can you _view source_ the page and see if there is a stray `"` character somewhere inside the `<a>` tag?

Comment: @Dipesh: looking at the edit, I hope none of the css classes have `display: none` or `visibility: hidden` in them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dipesh, maybe you have errors in the code *around* this snippet.

Try to check your code in isolation. I copied your code to the separate .php script with little set-up and checked `$actions` array with `print_r`, like this:

**edit_array.php**

```
<?php
$item = array();
$item['course_id'] = 1;
$actions = array(
    'EDIT'   => sprintf('<a href="admin-ajax.php?action=%s&subaction=%s&course_id=%d" class="%s" id="%s">Edit</a>',
        'abf_cm',
        'edit_course',
        $item['course_id'],
       'thickbox edit-box',
       'edit_'.$item['course_id']
     ),
    'DELETE'    => sprintf('<a href="?page=%s&task=%s&action=%s&bookid=%s&noheader=true">Delete</a>','course_management','do_process','delete',$item['course_id']),
);

print_r($actions);
```

I ran this script from console and got the following results:

```
$ php edit_array.php 
Array
(
    [EDIT] => <a href="admin-ajax.php?action=abf_cm&subaction=edit_course&course_id=1" class="thickbox edit-box" id="edit_1">Edit</a>
    [DELETE] => <a href="?page=course_management&task=do_process&action=delete&bookid=1&noheader=true">Delete</a>
)
```

Generated link for `$actions['EDIT']` is HTML valid, so one can safely conclude that your code itself is working fine, and error lies somewhere else.